# Android AES Encryption Missing Bytes after Cipher.doFinal

Tags: android, encryption, kotlin, aes

I'm trying to encrypt an inputstream from glide.

I converted the inputstream into a byte array and pass it in my encrypt methode:

```
fun encrypt(input: ByteArray): ByteArray {

    Log.e("TAG", "inputsize: ${input.size}")

    val iv           = ByteArray(KeyStoreHelper.IV_SIZE)
    val secureRandom = SecureRandom()
    secureRandom.nextBytes(iv)

    val c = Cipher.getInstance(KeyStoreHelper.AES_MODE)
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getKey(), GCMParameterSpec(KeyStoreHelper.GCM_SIZE, iv))
    Log.e("TAG", "outputsize: ${c.getOutputSize(input.size)}")
    val encodedBytes = c.doFinal(input)

    Log.e("TAG", "encodedBytesSize: ${encodedBytes.size}")

    val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( iv.size + encodedBytes.size)
    byteBuffer.put(iv)
    byteBuffer.put(encodedBytes)

    Log.e("TAG", "byteBuffer: ${byteBuffer.array().size}")


    return byteBuffer.array()
}
```

The logs look like this:

```
inputsize: 750683 
outputsize: 750699 
encodedBytesSize: 95339 
byteBuffer: 95351
```

As you can see, the encrypted image byte array is way to small and I dont get why - If i try to encrypt strings or smaller images (about 100kb-200kb) it works like a charm.

Thanks for helping me out!

Kind regards
Tom

Comment: Interesting, that may be a bug. Of course, the idea that you would first read everything in an array is a bad idea, but `doFinal` should not do that. Please indicate the runtime and libraries used (mainly the configured provider for the cipher (print out `c.getProvider().toString()`).

Comment: Hey Maarten, thanks for your response! Whats better practise than "first read everything in an array" - Its hard to find a good, working, relatively up to date example...
c.getProvider().toString() give me the following:
`AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround version 1.0`

Comment: Generally you could use `CipherInputStream` and `CipherOutputStream`, but check if it works with GCM on Android first; these streams have often been retrofitted to be compatible with GCM *afterwards*.

Comment: Ok, the workaround provider seems to have been added by Android itself, to make sure that then Android code is called instead of Bouncy Castle; so definitely something to do with the provider linked with Android, it seems.

Comment: I'm using already using GCM. AES_MODE is defined by:
`const val AES_MODE  = "AES/GCM/NoPadding"`
Let me know if you need more information, but thanks anyway for your help! I'm new to encryption and want to add a best best practice scenario :)

Comment: I'm saying that you should make sure that the streams work correctly with GCM, not your code. I suspect that they do, but test none-the-less. There have been some issues, especially with GCM / buffering, at least for Java SE.

Comment: Encrypting files with `CipherOutputStream` works (instead of using `c.doFinal`).
How could I add my IV to the CipherOutputStream for decryption?

Comment: You need to `init` your cipher first using the correct `GCMParameterSpec` constructor before passing it to the stream. GCM takes a nonce, by the way, but that's just nitpicking. Weird fact: 95339  is a prime number.

Comment: Yeah ok, but that means i need to store the IV somewhere, right? Cause the main idea was to put it at the begining of each string/file (first 12 bytes) and before decrypting get it back, and fill the init of the cipher with the IV.

Comment: Generally you connect the `CipherOutputStream` to another stream. You can write it first to that stream. A nonce can also be calculated or transmitted by other means, so it doesn't make sense for it to be part of the ciphertext (in my opinion the tag should not be part of the ciphertext either, by the way - at least not within an API).

Comment: That was to simple :D Thanks for helping me out, will work with `CipherOutputStream` and `CipherInputStream` for files :)

Comment: Cool. Kudo's for using the Android key store, GCM and a unique nonce. By the way, your `getKey` code needs urgent refactoring. A getter should not do all that behind the scenes, and you should not create catch-all methods such as these in the first place. Split it out into key generation, retrieval and algorithm init. This code does certainly not adhere to least surprise principles.

Comment: Alright, I will give it a little refactoring and split the function + remove the catch all. :)

Comment: I found out, like you said, that it has something todo with the Provider,... switchting to another Provider like AndroidOpenSSL works like a charm. Also CipherInputStream/Outputstreams a extremly slow with AndroidKeyStore Provider.

Comment: Yeah, that one is security over speed, in all likelihood. Of course, I'd expect proper bounds checks and tests for code that is considered secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you've run into a bug, weirdly enough at an illogical location: 95339 is a prime number. You'd almost think that some developer left in that value by purpose, in case he forgot or to test the test team.

However, it is not a good idea to cache all data in memory for such large swaths of information, even for GCM. You should try and use streaming instead. You can use the `CipherOutputStream` to perform encryption and `CipherInputStream` for decryption. You can connect these streams to other streams such as `FileOutputStream` and `FileInputStream` to directly read / write to the filesystem. It is also possible to write the IV to these underlying streams.

Beware that there may be big differences in how GCM is handled by different providers. As you've noticed, the one associated with the Android key store was build for security - of the key anyway - rather than speed. Other implementations of GCM may not show this bug. Beware that the available providers may differ between different Java(-esk) platforms and versions of these platforms.